# Uninstalling the VS2010 extension without the Extension Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to uninstall the VS2010 extension correctly without the Extension Manager? I couldn't find any special command line arguments for .vsix file and think that just deleting all the files from Visual Studio's special place is not a right solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, actually deleting the folder is exactly what you should do. A "pure" VSIX extension is just a unzip of the files to a folder under %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions.

It's a good idea to check though that it wasn't installed through MSI or some other installer technology by verifying in Windows Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: With Visual Studio you can just use the Tools > Extensions and Updates menu (Nuget) to remove/nuke .vsixes.

Comment: +1 Thanks, the "Collapse Selection In Solution Explorer" had stopped working for my VS (the button no longer displayed).  But deleting the dir, I could then reinstall this vsix, which fixed my problem.

Comment: @Michael, the original question asked "without the Extension Manager" (called Extensions and Updates in VS 2012+). Of course, if you can, uninstalling via the Extension Manager is the way to go!